# How to execute an anchor\href in my javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor, href

I'm trying to figure this one out but my mind has just gone blank.

- I have a button element on my webpage with an id: e.g `<button id="someId"></button>`
- In the document.ready function, I have an on click event which occurs when the user clicks the button. e.g. `$('#someId').on('click', function() {`
- In this event there is an if statement which determines a value. Depending on the value, I want to execute a href in an anchor but I can't figure out the syntax.

The reason I am trying to execute the anchor in the javascript is because i'm passing a variable into the href. It could be true or false.

Here is what I have\what I'm trying to do. Any help would be great.

```
if (date1 <= date2) {
   //I want to execute this anchor
   <a href="@{Application.openthispage(true)}"></a>
}else{
   //otherwise execute this anchor
   <a href="@{Application.openthispage(false)}"></a>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The window.location method posted by Eli is the correct way to visit a link using JavaScript. However, if you can use a link instead of a button, you could just set the href of the link in the onclick. Here is a sample jsFiddle that visits a different url based on whether one input is greater than the other:
http://jsfiddle.net/jw3Pd/

So when the user clicks the link, set the href to whatever link you want the user to visit.

```
$("#someId").on("click", function () { 
   if (date1 <= date2) {
      //I want to execute this anchor
      $("#someId").attr("href", "@{Application.openthispage(true)}");
   } else{
      //otherwise execute this anchor
      $("#someId").attr("href", "@{Application.openthispage(false)}");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You're looking at the problem wrong.  An anchor is a static HTML element that, when clicked, changes the current window location (i.e. URL).  The JS equivalent looks something like this: `window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';`.  So by setting `window.location.href` you will use JS to navigate to another URL.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll use it going forward.